# Weak Derivative of $x \mapsto \ln(|x|)$ doesn't exists in $(-1,1)$ but in $B_1(0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: logarithms, weak-derivatives

How can I show that $f: (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}, \ x \mapsto \ln(|x|)$ has no weak derivative but in $B_1(0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ it has? I know that every classical solution is also a weak solution in this case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you considering $\ln|x|$ as a function $\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ and then $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x_1^2+x_2^2)$ as a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: and from what I understand, if $D^\alpha f$ is in $L^1_{loc}$ then it is clearly the weak derivative of $f$, hence it should reduce to proving that $\frac{x_1}{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ is in $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Comment: yes $ln|x|$ with R-->R! But then in the exercise they only tell, that in $B_1(0)$ I should find a weak derivative on $x_1$. Nothing more. i would guess that your solution  also works with that, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be help you by showing that $\ln|\cdot|: (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}_{<0}$ is not weakly differentiable.

> **Lemma:**
>   Let $u'$ be the weak derivative of $u$ on $(a,b)$. Then for all intervals $(\alpha, \beta) \subset (a,b)$ it holds that $u'|_{(\alpha, \beta)}$ is also the weak derivative of $u|_{(\alpha, \beta)}$ on $(\alpha, \beta)$.

**Proof.**
Let $(\alpha, \beta) \subset (a,b)$ and $\phi \in \mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}^{\infty}(\alpha, \beta)$ and define the trivial extension of $\phi$ by $\tilde{\phi} \in \mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}^{\infty}(a,b)$.
Then, we conclude
\begin{equation*}
  \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} u(x) \phi'(x) dx
  = \int_{a}^{b} u(x) \tilde{\phi}'(x) dx
  = - \int_{a}^{b} u'(x) \tilde{\phi}(x) dx
  = - \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} u'(x) \phi(x) dx,
\end{equation*}
which implies the proposition.$\ \square$

**Back to your question:**
This implies that the only candidate for the weak derivative of your function has to be
\begin{equation*}
\omega(x) = \begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{x}, & \text{if } x \in (-1,0), \\
\frac{1}{x}, & \text{if } x \in (0,1)
\end{cases}.
\end{equation*}
Now, for all $\phi \in \mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}((-1,1))$ (with $\phi(-1) = \phi(1) = 0$ ($\star$)) we have by integration by parts (IBP)
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1} \ln(|x|) \phi'(x) \, dx
& = \int_{-1}^{0} \ln(-x) \phi'(x) \, dx + \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x) \phi'(x) \, dx \\
& \overset{\textrm{(IBP)}}{=} \big[\ln(-x) \phi(x) \big]_{x = - 1}^{0} + \int_{-1}^{0} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx + 
\big[\ln(x) \phi(x) \big]_{x = 0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx \\
& = - \int_{-1}^{1} \omega(x) \phi(x) \, dx + \big[\ln(-x) \phi(x) \big]_{x = - 1}^{0} + \big[\ln(x) \phi(x) \big]_{x = 0}^{1} \\
& \overset{(\star)}{=} \int_{-1}^{1} \omega(x) \phi(x) \, dx + \lim_{x \nearrow 0} \ln(-x) + \lim_{x \searrow 0} \ln(x) \\
& \neq - \int_{-1}^{1} \omega(x) \phi(x) \, dx.
\end{align*}
and therefore, your function is not weakly differentiable on $(-1,1)$.